# Renaming Object using @JsonProperty not working

Tags: jackson

I have a JSON

```
"workingHours":{
   "THU":{"startHour":"09:30","endHour":"18:40"},
   "TUE":{"startHour":"01:30","endHour":"18:30"},
   "SAT":{"startHour":"09:30","endHour":"11:45"},
   "WED":{"startHour":"09:30","endHour":"18:35"},
   "FRI":{"startHour":"09:30","endHour":"18:45"},
   "MON":{"startHour":"13:30","endHour":"18:25"},
   "SUN":{}
}}}
```

I am converting this to POJO and renaming the objects. But when I try to read the Object from POJO getting null value. I need to read startHour but when I do getThu() getting null value

```
 @JsonProperty("THU")
  private Thu thu;

 @JsonProperty("THU")
 public Thu getThu() {
    return thu;
 }

 @JsonProperty("THU")
  public void setThu(Thu thu) {
    this.thu = thu;
}
```